# Python, mail is not being received

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am using `smtplib` to send mail but neither mail being sent nor I am getting error. The code given below:

```
    import smtplib
    import textwrap
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText

    msg = {}
    msg['From'] = 'me@mydomain.me'
    msg['To'] = 'yours@gmail.com'
    msg['Subject'] = "This is TEST"
    TEXT = 'HAY BUDDY'

    server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.mydomain.me', 26)
    server.login("user@mydomain.me", "xxx")
    message = textwrap.dedent("""\
        From: %s
        To: %s
        Subject: %s
        %s
        """ % (msg['From'], msg['To'], msg['Subject'], TEXT))

    print(message)
    server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], message)
    server.quit()
```

Comment: Did it connect to the smtp server?

Comment: Yes it did. AS I said I found no error either

Comment: I just tested your program by using smtplib.SMTP_SSL('server', 465), and It is fine.

Comment: Two things, are there any logs on the SMTP server? Secondly, I see you are using port 26 for the SMTP, when the default is 25, is it wanted?

Comment: @asettouf because this is what offered by hosting, port 26

Comment: @Volatil3 I see, now more importantly, do you have access to the server "mail.mydomain.me" to retrieve the logs to see what happened on the server. It seems it acknowledge your request, however it is unclear what happens afterward and the logs could possibly point to the issue (an example for me would be for instance an issue forwarding the mail to gmail, because of network issue, or dns issue...etc)